# How to open a post in PHP when clicking it, a good approach

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

So I have a list of posts and when clicking on it, it should direct me to that particular post. Basically the way I code this is adding the id of the post to the end of the link, like posts/1 which will take me to the post with the id of 1. This is a basic design, because I see on many sites they do not have such urls...do they post the data to the new page? Or what is a better design to do this?

Comment: Most sites I know uses either a random id or a large integer for their entity's ID, for example, this question's URL is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257811, so I think it's a pretty standard design to use /entities/<entity_id>

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how StackOverflow (among others) does this and it is good practice indeed. This is the URL of your post:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257811/how-to-open-a-post-in-php-when-clicking-it-a-good-approach
```

The "/questions/9257811" segment is the id of the post. The other part is optional and is only used for Search Engine Optimization. Try to load `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257811/WRONG-DESCRIPTION` and see for yourself.

Edit: I couldn't use a wrong description in the above link, StackOverflow was correcting it automatically. It's easy to get the title once you get the id, which is how they autocorrect it. This avoids links like "/posts/34234/offensive-words-here" for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the best way to send and receive an id in the URL. Most webpages do it this way. You have a link (example: `<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/post.php?id=1">Post #1</a>`.).

When applying url-rewrite it simply "prettify" the url by making it look this way `http://www.yoursite.com/post/1`, but in fact, the url is actully still the same. You can access it with `$_GET['id']` was usual.

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ. Though most sites uses it (and i admit, numericals are more convenient for refer), a friendly approach is, using the title of the post. But you need to do a lot of extra steps to make it error free (such as, no post can have identical titles, using a dash or underscore between the words for flexibility plus filtering the url should be more strict and becomes complicated in this case). If you want to avoid all these hussle, use ids as they are easier to implement.